# Is there a way to create a named function in clojure which is only visible in function scope?

Tags: clojure, scope, scheme

In ***Scheme*** I can do something like this:

```
(define (adder)
  (define (one) 1)
  (define (two) 2)
  (+ (one) (two)))
```

Calling `adder` results in `3` while calling `one` will yield an error since `one` is only visible within the scope of `adder`.

In ***Clojure*** if I do something similar

```
(defn adder []
  (defn one [] 1)
  (defn two [] 2)
  (+ (one) (two)))
```

`one` and `two` will pollute my namespace since `defn` uses `def` internally which creates bindings in the current namespace.

Is there a function/macro which creates named functions in local scope?

*The reason for my question is that I got used to the way Scheme works. Naming my local functions that way often makes my code more readable.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [letfn](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/letfn):

> Takes a vector of function specs and a body, and generates a set of
>   bindings of functions to their names. All of the names are available
>   in all of the definitions of the functions, as well as the body.

```
 (defn adder []
   (letfn [(one [] 1)
           (two [] 2)]
     (+ (one) (two))))
```

Answer (score 9):

Additionally to Alex's excellent answer, any `fn` can be named.

```
(defn adder []
  (let [one (fn [] 1)
        two (fn [] (+ (one) (one)))]
    (+ (one) (two))))
```

This is useful if you already have a `let` block.

If an `fn` refers to itself, it needs a name of its own

```
(defn silly []
  (let [constant 5
        thing (fn thong
                ([a] (+ a constant))
                ([] (inc (thong constant))))]
    (* (thing) (thing))))
```

The name the `fn` is bound to need not be the same as the name it knows itself by.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function that is visible to the current namespace but not visible by other namespaces - you can use [**defn-**](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defn-)

> > **defn-**
> >     *macro*
> >     Usage: (defn- name & decls)
> >     same as defn, yielding non-public def

from http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/defn-

```
user=> (ns test)
nil

test=> (defn- foo [] "World!")
#'test/foo

test=> (defn bar [] (str "Hello " (foo)))
#'test/bar

test=> (foo)
"World!"
test=> (bar)
"Hello World!"
test=> (ns playground)
nil
playground=> (test/bar)
"Hello World!"

;; Error will be thrown
;; var: #'test/foo is not public
playground=> (test/foo)
```

Comment: I was talking about function scope only. `defn-` is not applicable here although I appreciate you pointing this option out.

Comment: No problem. **let** or **letfn** as the others stated is definitely what you are looking for.